# Certain games won't load - Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

Certain games on Steam won't load. I can't figure out why. I upgraded to kernel 3.14.4 from 3.13.39 and this problem won't go away:

```
[   81.122225] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
[   81.593271] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   81.593276] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  343.22  Thu Sep 11 16:27:43 PDT 2014
[   81.610223] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   81.610534] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[   81.614761] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.614842] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.614870] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.614896] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.614919] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.614944] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.614986] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   81.615010] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   82.652914] ACPI Error: Field [TMPB] at 274432 exceeds Buffer [ROM1] size 262144 (bits) (20131218/dsopcode-236)
[   82.652920] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ROM] (Node ffff88022647fa00), AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20131218/psparse-536)
[   82.669967] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   82.841451] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[   83.314224] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   83.318847] [drm] Module unloaded
[   83.320680] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[   83.320691] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20131218/nsarguments-95)
[   83.337618] pci 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D0
```

My Xorg.8.log

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.8.log | grep EE
[    81.498] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    81.498] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    81.498] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    81.498] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    81.498] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    81.498] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "true"
[    81.498] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"
[    81.499] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseEDID" "false"
[    81.499] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
[    81.499] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    81.499] (**) NVIDIA(0): Ignoring EDIDs
[    81.499] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "UseDisplayDevice" set to "none"; enabling NoScanout
[    81.499] (**) NVIDIA(0):     mode
[    82.727] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Found DRM driver nvidia-drm (20130102)
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GT 750M (GK107) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    82.728] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    82.728] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.07.9a.00.4b
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    82.728] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce GT 750M at PCI:1:0:0
[    82.728] (--) NVIDIA(0):     none
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "NULL"
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 640 x 480
[    82.728] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[    82.728] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (75, 75); computed from built-in default
[    82.728] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA: Using 3072.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    82.728] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    82.731] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "NULL"
[    82.731] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initiate mode change.
[    82.731] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to complete mode change
[    82.738] Loading extension NV-GLX
[    82.741] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    82.741] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    82.741] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    82.742] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    82.742] Loading extension NV-CONTROL
```